# Unix command to check the filesize

Tags: unix

I need to check the display the `files`  my server with their sizes.Which command that I need to use.
Any variants of `ls` command?

Comment: What has become of the good old tradition of reading the manual pages? `man ls`, man!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I hope `ls -lah` will do the job. Also if you are new to unix environment please go to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-useful-commands.htm

Comment: Ye, `ls -lah` did exactly what I wanted, listing size of all folders and files in current directory.

Answer (score 31):

```
stat -c %s file.txt
```

This command will give you the size of the file in bytes. You can learn more about why you should avoid parsing output of ls command over here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Getting `stat illegal option -c` error on macOS, used `stat -f "%z" file.txt` instead

Answer (score 18):

```
ls -l --block-size=M
```

will give you a long format listing (needed to actually see the file size) and round file sizes up to the nearest MiB.
If you want MB (10^6 bytes) rather than MiB (2^20 bytes) units, use --block-size=MB instead.

Or

```
ls -lah
```

-h
When used with the -l option, use unit suffixes: Byte, Kilobyte, Megabyte, Gigabyte, Terabyte and Petabyte in order to reduce the number of digits to three or less using base 2 for sizes.

```
man ls
```

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls

Comment: `ls -lah` lists size for all elements, folders and files, in current directory, that's perfect this!

Answer (score 6):

Here's yet another option to add to the mix:

```
$ du -b file.txt
```

That is: estimate file space usage of file.txt in bytes.

Comment: Also, `du -BM file.txt` will give you MiB. `-BMB` will give you MB. Works similarly with `K`, `KB`, `G`, `GB`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Bit late but here is a better solution imo to Big McLargeHuge's answer

```
$ du -h *
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:`ls -lh`, then you will get a list of file information

Answer (score -1):

```
ls -lh file.txt | awk '{ print $5 }'
```

Comment: No, don't parse the output of `ls` - that's not at all safe or reliable.  Use `stat` to extract properties of files.

Comment: I think this is perfectly acceptable for what its worth. Thanks @piniyini

Comment: Me too. I'd add `-h` to improve human readability

Comment: I'm actually here trying to find alternatives to stat which seems to be non-standard, at least on MacOS, for what it's worth.