# How do I count characters in bash using if statement?

Tags: bash, if-statement

Using an if statement in bash, I want count number of characters for files that are 1000 bytes. If the file is greater than 1000 bytes, then I want it to echo "Skipping Filename"

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=$(/usr/bin/ls $@)
echo $FILES $@
for f in $FILES
do
   echo "Processing $f file..."    
if [ $FILES | wc -c) -gt 1000 ]
then
    echo "Skipping $"
elif [ $FILES | wc -c) -eq 1000 ]
then
# count number of characters and output that for file $f
    wc -c $f
fi

done
```

Is this how I'd go about it?

Comment: paste you script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: When you say *count number of characters and output that for file $f* , Do you want to append the output of `wc -c` to the file itself?

Comment: [Do not parse the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) and [Do not parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52800/how-to-do-an-if-statement-from-the-result-of-an-executed-command

Comment: @cr96 : Please make your script first syntactically correct. As it is written, I don't have any idea what it is supposed to do. In any case, you should get errors from it.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file with `cat "$f"` and count the bytes with `wc -c`, then test if the result is greater than 1000 with `... -gt 1000`.

```sh
...
if [ $(cat "$f" | wc -c) -gt 1000 ]; then
    ...
else
    ...
fi
...
```

Comment: This solution, albeit correct, seems a little to heavy... what about a file of 1G? The size of a file can be read in other *quicker* ways.

Comment: On big files the better solution is `stat --format=%s filename` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845057/unix-command-to-check-the-filesize/51199065)

Comment: `stat` has different syntax and it varies from OS/system. The syntax that works on a GNU system will/might not work on a *BSD and others. Whereas with `wc` POSIX requires the `-c` flag see [POSIX wc](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, without the use of `ls`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob ##: Just in case there are no files.
files=(*)

for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  printf 'Processing %s file...\n' "$f"
  byte_count=$(wc -c < "$f")
  if (( byte_count > 1000 )); then
    printf 'Skipping %s\n' "$f"
  elif (( byte_count == 1000 )); then
    printf '%d: %s\n' "$byte_count" "$f"
  fi
done
```

---

- It needs more error checking like if there are no files or if the file being process is not a text file and so on.
- See  [How can I check whether a directory is empty or not? How do I check for any *.mpg files, or count how many there are?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004)

---

Using your logic for the `"$@"` from your post. Taking into account about what `@kvantour` mentioned in the comments.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files=("$@")

for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  [[ -e $f ]] || {
    printf '%s no such file or directory skipping...\n' "$f"
    continue
  }
  [[ -d $f ]] && {
    printf '%s is a directory skipping...\n' "$f"
    continue
  }
  printf 'Processing %s file...\n' "$f"
  byte_count=$(wc -c < "$f")
  if ((  byte_count > 1000 )); then
    printf '%s has more than 1000 bytes.\n' "$f"
  elif (( byte_count == 1000 )); then
    printf '%s has %d bytes.\n' "$f" "$byte_count"
  else
    printf '%s has less than 1000 bytes.\n' "$f"
  fi
done
```

---

The second script can be run with the file as arguments with either absolute or relative path. Assuming the name of your script is `myscript`

```
./myscript file1 file2 file2
```

Or

```
./mscrypt *.mp4 *.mp3 *.txt *.csv
```

Or just a plain glob

```
./myscript *
```

---

With the absolute path

```
./myscript /path/to/file
```

Or

```
./myscript /path/to/*.mp3
```

Or just a plain glob

```
./myscript /path/to/*
```

---

The test for file type can be improve. See `help test` or the `file` command. Something like:

```
file --mime-type -b file.txt
```

If your `file` command supports it.

Comment: You still need to check if `$f` is an actual file. It is possible that the content of `files` is an invalid file (such as `*` in this case or an invalid file-argument in the OP)

Comment: @kvantour, thank you for that comment. Added a `nullglob`.

Comment: In case of your example, this would work. In case of the OP where `files=( "$@" )` this could still fail if an argument is `foo` and no file `foo` exists.